# IIS URL Rewrite: Match URL with and without Slash

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I want to redirect specific URLs permanently to other domains.

```
<rule name="URL Test" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url="^en/career/jobs$" />
              <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">                   
                   
              </conditions>
              <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/newjobs" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
```

It works when I use https://source.com/en/career/jobs
but when I add a slash in the end (https://source.com/en/career/jobs/), it doesnt work.

How can I accept both variants in the match url ?

Comment: If you learn a little bit more about regular expressions, you will see that using `^en/career/jobs$` exactly leads to that behavior. Change to another pattern and you can see something different. You don't need others to help but help yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change your parameters to match both `en/career/jobs/` and `en/career/jobs`. You can use the following rules as a reference:

```
<rule name="URL Test" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^en/career/jobs(.*)$" />            
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/newjobs" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```